# Run a different batch file when one coses

Tags: batch-file

I have 2 batch files (1.bat and 2.bat). I want 2.bat to run when 1.bat closes. Is that possible?

Or is there a way to close a batch file when a batch file closes. Here is my code which doesnt work:

```
cd C:\xampp
start apache_start.bat
cd C:\Users\MinecraftServer\Desktop\1.12.2MinecraftServer
MC1.12.2Start.bat
taskkill /F /IM cmd.exe /T
```

I have a minecraft server running with a .bat file and a web server running off of a .bat file (using xampp, its used for prtg monitorng).

Comment: I commend to your attention [SS64 on `CALL`](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html).

Answer (score 0):

`start` will create a completely independent process and continue immediately to your next batch command. That independent process may do a job and terminate, or may say open an application like `notepad` and wait until the `notepad` is closed. Regardless, a straight `start` command will not stop the batch that it is in - the next step will be executed, whether or not the process that has been started has terminated.

You can also add the `/wait` switch to `start`. If this switch is used, the batch will wait until the `start`ed process terminates.

Preferred syntax for `start` is

```
start /wait "window title" executable parameters...
```

where "window title" may be an empty, but not absent string. Including this as the first parameter is preferred because the first quoted string in a `start` command is used as a window title for the `start`ed process, and thus `start` may not act as expected where the executable or any of its parameters is quoted.

`call executablename...` will wait for that executable to terminate before progressing to the next step. This may or may not be what is desired.

`MC1.12.2Start.bat` in your code will **SWITCH** to that batch and remaining batch lines will be ignored.

Which may be fortunate in this case, since as you've coded it, the `apache_start.bat` may or may not have completed when the `taskkill` command is run, killing all `cmd.exe` sessions.